# Android app, HttpURLConnection GET method, AsyncTask getting tag instead of result

Tags: java, android, url

It is simple app that needs to send two numbers using GET and reads back.

```
Button btnSaberi;
    EditText txtAunos, txtBunos;
    TextView txtIspis;
    String sturl = "http://xxx.xxx.xx.x/PhpProject1/index.php";
    Integer a, b;
    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection;
    URL url;
    public void posalji(View view){
    a = Integer.parseInt(txtAunos.getText().toString());
    b = Integer.parseInt(txtBunos.getText().toString());
    sturl = sturl+"?a=" + a + "&b=" + b;
    new Posalji().execute(sturl);
}

class Posalji extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        txtIspis.setText("Rezultat je : " + s);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {
            url = new URL(strings[0]);
            httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpURLConnection.connect();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));
            rez = br.readLine();
        }
        return rez;
    }
}
}
```

Using Emulator.

I have changed and now instead of showing me php output it shows me html tag.

```
"<!DOCTYPE html>"
```

Comment: Take a good look at your method. First off you didn't give us the visibility (public private etc.) and secondly you didn't give us the return type. finally look at what your method is returning all the time.

Comment: you really gave me headache :D you are asking for more code yet stackoverflow is telling me that there is more code than my text.

Comment: That is because they want to prevent posts that say something like this: I'm getting a null pointer exception, here's my code: //puts 4-5 classes of code in post with no further explanation or words on what they've tried or want to acomplish

Comment: ive added all the methods

Comment: 2 things void should be lowercase in your method sig and your method has a return null at the end that doesn't need to be there.

Comment: actually it gives an error if i change that

Comment: show your logcat error please

Comment: What is crash get it from logcat

Comment: updated, ive pasted logcat pic

Answer (score 0):

Please remove txtIspis.setText("Rezultat je : " + br.readLine()); line from AsyncTask doInBackground. In doInBackground we never update UI like this. you can use onPostExecute for update your textbox values.

Please read this doc https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask

Comment: are you try it?

Answer (score 0):

As you are calling br.readLine(); just once, it is reading only the first line of data from the BufferedReader. 
To read all the lines of data from BufferedReader you need to use a loop.

Update your doInBackground method

```
@Override 
protected String doInBackground(String... params){
   String url = params[0];
   String result;

   try {
      URL myUrl = new URL(url);

      HttpURLConnection connection =(HttpURLConnection) myUrl.openConnection();
      connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
      connection.connect()

      InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());      
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
      StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
      String inputLine;

      while((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null){
         stringBuilder.append(inputLine);
      }

      reader.close();
      streamReader.close();

      result = stringBuilder.toString();
   }
   return result;   
}
```

Comment: i have changed and it shows me whole page, but all i want is to get result echoed by php, and not whole page with tags, is there way to do it

Comment: Use [Postman App](https://www.getpostman.com/), to check the output of your url. I think what you need is to create a separate page which will only output the data that you want to load into your app.